# Nest, serverless: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: node.js, lambda, nestjs, serverless, node.js-fs

My project has above project structure

```
   src 
     ---- Clone(empty folder)
     ---- app.module.ts
     ---- app.service.ts
```

serverless

```
  functions:
    main:
      timeout: 60
      handler: src/main.handler
      events:
      - schedule: cron(40 22 ? * MON *)
```

service trigger s3 bucket at the scheduler time and a data CSV file should be pushed to GitHub. When GitHub clones, it always clones into the src/clone folder. when running locally serverless it works properly but when deploying the "No such file or directory" an error comes. I can't see the clone folder after unzipping the sls package zip file. any one can help me solve this problem